# Unity in WP8 App - Flickering and pausing player

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I am porting an unity app to windows phone 8. Its basically just an animated background. While changing the data inside my wp8 project i am updating the unity background. 
I need to put an pivot control on top of the background. The background of the pivot is transparent. While changing the selected item the pivot control starts to flicker and even disappears somethings (its returning when the manipulation is completed).
The pivot control works fine, without the unity background.

I tried to pause the unity game while manipulating the pivot control but this doesnt work.
Here is the code of pausing the game in Unity.

```
void PauseGame(bool p)
{
    if (p)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
    }
    else Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
}
```

I also tried to `UnityApp.Obscure` and `UnityApp.Unobscure` the unity input, but that doesnt work either. I even tried to hide the `DrawingSurfaceBackground` and setting an image in front of it, but still no luck.

Is there a way to pause the unity player out of my wp8 solution (like `UnityPlayer.Pause()`)? Where I dont have to call a  function in Unity (like the `PauseGame()`)? I need the animated background while the pivot is not manipulated.

Thanks in advance.

robidd

Answer (score 0):

I've found out why the pivot control flickers on manipulation.
I have set the Background to black and the opacity to 0.7. By removing those attributes the flickering stopped. Now i dont need to stop the unity player.
I set an black image with opacity 0.7 instead of the pivot background and now it all works.